# Synchronising N sibling processes after fork

Tags: c, unix, synchronization, fork, ipc

I'm having some hard time with synchronising N child process waiting each one of them to arrive at some specific point.
I've tried semaphores and signals but I can't get my head around it.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

#define NUM_KIDS 4

void handle(int signum);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    sem_t* sem;
    sem = sem_open("/ok", O_CREAT, 0);
    signal(SIGUSR1, handle);

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_KIDS; i++) {
        switch(fork()) {
            case 0:
                fprintf(stderr, "ready %d from %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                /* i would like that each child stop here untill everyone is ready */
                for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) 
                fprintf(stderr, "lot of stuff\n");
                exit(0);
            break;
            default:
                /* unleashing the kids when everyone is ready */
                wait(NULL);
                fprintf(stderr, "OK\n");

            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void handle(int signum) {;}
```

And I believe that the output should be (once the child are sync)

```
ready ... from xxx
ready ... from xxx
ready ... from xxx
ready ... from xxx
...lots of stuff... 10 times
...lots of stuff... 10 times
...lots of stuff... 10 times
...lots of stuff... 10 times
```

Comment: You've got many superfluous headers and some superfluous code in your 'nearly but not quite an MCVE ([MCVE])' code.  The semaphore and signal code seems to be irrelevant.

Comment: I've tried so many workaround that leaving them there was easier

Comment: That's fine for while you're playing on your machine — it's not OK when you're asking a question on SO.  The code you present on SO should be an MCVE — minimal means "no superfluous code".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Synchronization

There's a simple trick:

- Create a pipe before you fork anything.
- Have the children each close the write end of the pipe.
- Have the children read from the pipe when you want to synchronize them.
- Have the parent close both ends of the pipe when the children should be started.
- Have the children close the read end of the pipe when they're released, so that the resources are released.
- The children now do 'their thing' (grow up, produce output, die).
- The parent now waits for its children to die (it's a morbid business when you're playing with processes on Unix).

If done correctly, the children all get EOF (zero bytes read) at the same time because there's no longer any process that can write to the pipe.  (That's why it is important for the children to close the write end of the pipe before doing the synchronizing `read()`.)

If you want the parent to know that the children are all ready, create two pipes before forking anything.  The parent process closes the write end of this second pipe, and then reads from the read end.  The children all close both ends of the pipe before settling into their `read()` call on the first pipe.  The parent process gets EOF when all the children have closed the write end of the pipe, so it knows the children have all started, at least as far as closing the second pipe.  The parent can then close the first pipe to release the children (and close the read end of the second pipe).

#### Don't wait too soon!

You are waiting in the `default` clause of the switch, which is not correct.  You need all four child processes launched before you do any waiting — otherwise they'll never all be able to synchronize.  When you do wait, you'll need to do your waiting in a (new) loop.  And, while debugging, you should add print statements to identify what is going on in the parent process.  For example, you'll print the status of the processes that exit, and their PID:

```
int corpse;
int status;
while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
    printf("%d: child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", (int)getpid(), corpse, status);
```

#### Working code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define NUM_KIDS 4

int main(void)
{
    int p_pipe[2];
    int c_pipe[2];
    char c;
    if (pipe(p_pipe) != 0 || pipe(c_pipe) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Oops: failed to create pipes\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_KIDS; i++)
    {
        switch (fork())
        {
        case 0:
            fprintf(stderr, "ready %d from %d\n", (int)getpid(), (int)getppid());
            close(p_pipe[0]);
            close(p_pipe[1]);
            close(c_pipe[1]);
            read(c_pipe[0], &c, 1);
            close(c_pipe[0]);
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                fprintf(stderr, "lot of stuff\n");
            return NUM_KIDS + i;
        case -1:
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to fork child %d\n", i+1);
            return 1;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    close(p_pipe[1]);
    read(p_pipe[0], &c, 1);
    printf("%d: %d children started\n", (int)getpid(), NUM_KIDS);
    close(c_pipe[0]);
    close(c_pipe[1]);

    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) >= 0)
        printf("%d: child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", (int)getpid(), corpse, status);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample run

```
ready 81949 from 81948
ready 81950 from 81948
ready 81951 from 81948
ready 81952 from 81948
81948: 4 children started
lot of stuff
lot of stuff
lot of stuff
lot of stuff
…lines omitted for brevity…
lot of stuff
lot of stuff
lot of stuff
lot of stuff
81948: child 81951 exited with status 0x0600
81948: child 81952 exited with status 0x0700
81948: child 81950 exited with status 0x0500
81948: child 81949 exited with status 0x0400
```

Comment: probably I'm missing something
I create 2 pippes

The child:
close the wirte of the first pipe,
do its thing,
close both ends of the second pipe,
read from the first pipe //here should hang every child,
close read end first pipe.

the parent
close write end second pipe,
read from the second pipe (here should hang?),
close read end second pipe,
close write end first pipe.

thanks for your time jonathan

Comment: See updated answer with code and sample output.  Your PIDs will be different, of course.

Comment: oh god thank a lot, that damn switch was messing around thanks again

Comment: Note that if you don't want the children to do anything if the parent fails to launch one of the children, then revise things so that the children pay attention to the return value from `read()`, not doing anything if they get 0 and running if they get 1.  The parent then writes one byte per child to the pipe if it is successful in launching them all.  As long as each child only tries to read a single byte, everything should still be synchronized.