# Obtaining the status of execv without stopping the execution of the parent

Tags: c

Is there a way to obtain the status of a command run with execv without waiting for it with `waitpid` or `wait`?

The program I need to do reads other executable program as argument and need to print the status of this program when executed with `execv` exactly when the command is finished executing, but needs to keep executing after the `fork` instead of waiting for the program passed as argument to finish executing.

Here is what I have right now which doesn't seem to capture any status:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio_ext.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

int status;

void child_exit_handler(int signal)
{
  int pid = wait(&status);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pid_t pid;

  signal(SIGCHLD, child_exit_handler);

  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
  {
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
    {

      char *cmd[4];
      cmd[0] = "sh";
      cmd[1] = "-c";
      cmd[2] = argv[i];
      cmd[3] = NULL;

      execv("/bin/bash", cmd);
    }
  }

  if (pid > 0)
  {
    // do something;
    // later do something with status
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean multiprocessing maybe ?

Comment: Are you suggesting that I make a function with what the parent does and launch a thread with that function just before calling the wait, or something like that? I'm not an expert in multithreading so just trying to make sure I'm following.

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53892695/13000695 answer your question ? Long answer there but I think that could help you somehow. Btw : I mean multiprocessing not multithreading. I dont know for other language if there is difference but in C the difference is huge.

Comment: You didn't show what you want to do with the status, but I hacked a bit into your program and it works fine here. Why are you saying it doesn't capture any status?

BTW, your `cmd` array should have length 4.

Comment: `man 3 execv` - `"The exec() functions return only if an error has occurred."`

Comment: @Carl Norum when I pass an argument which execute a kill it doesn't return a 15 as it should but a 0. But I have another problem anyway, since I fork inside the parent and it probably pass the global variable status to the fork before the wait even do its thing.

Comment: execute what kind of kill? `kill` probably returned success as expected... it's the thing you killed that would give a different status.

Comment: A strict shell executing ```kill $$``` is the program passed as argument, when I simply make a ```wait``` inside the parent it returns 15.

Comment: I cannot show the full program unfortunately, but I will look into multiprocessing.

Comment: are you sure you quote the `$$` properly when running it? Just checked that and it's also fine here.

Comment: You are right, I made it work for the small program but it doesn't work in my full program and I think it's because of forking in the parent so the child as a copy of the status but the status doesn't change since the signal is send in the parent program instead of the child. Now the problem is that you can't share variable between child and parent process. Thanks for you help.