# How can I list all the child pids before passing them control?

Tags: c, multithreading, process, fork, wait

I have an assignment where the professor asks for the parent process to print the process id of each child process before passing control to the child process.

I tried doing something like this:

```
pid_t cpids[5]; //I want to create 5 child processes
int n = 0;

do {
    cpids[n++] = fork();
} while(cpids[n] > 0 && n < 5) ; //This doesn't fork 5 times

//print all the child pids
printf("The child processes are: %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", cpids[0]..);
//(I know this would be printed multiple times, I'm just trying to explain what I need)

//then after printing the ids, tell child processes what to do
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    //error
    if(cpids[i] < 0) {
        printf("There was an error with fork()\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //child process
    else if(cpids[i] == 0) {
    //...reads from pipe sent from parent process
    }

    //parent process
    //sends message through pipe to child process
    //waits for child to terminate
}
```

So this definitely didn't work :). Is there a simpler way to fork processes without immediately giving it instructions? Thanks!

//UPDATE

So I know I'm doing the fork() thing wrong. This was my original code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //error
    if((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        printf("There was an error with fork()\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //child process
    else if(pid == 0) {
        pid = getpid();
        close(fd[i][1]);

        //read starting position from parent process
        len = read(fd[i][0], &fpos, sizeof(fpos));

        if(len > 0) {
            doChild(numArray, fpos, i);
        }

        printf("id: %d\n", pid);
        _exit(1);
    } 

    //parent process
    else {
        close(fd[i][0]);
        fpos = (SIZE/NUM_CHILD) * i;
        write(fd[i][1], &fpos, sizeof(fpos));

        if ( waitpid(-getpid(), &status, 0) != -1 ) {
            if ( WIFEXITED(status) ) {
                int returned = WEXITSTATUS(status);
                printf("child id: %d ended with status %d\n\n", pid, returned);
            }
        }

        else {
            perror("waitpid() failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

}
```

However, the parent process has to wait for the child process to terminate before another child process can start. There's no way I can get the child pids before they all start running. I'm basically looking for a way to create all the child processes I need, maybe have them sleep right after they're created, then print out all of their pids from the parent process before they continue.

Comment: After you fork, you need to check if the current process is parent or child. And to the work accordingly. Here you are spanning the whole tree where children have their own children.

Comment: You're forking lots more than 5 times. After the first fork, both the parent and child continue the `for` loop. The parent forks 5 times, the first child forks 4 times, the second child forks 3 times, and so on. You're forgetting that the child process runs all the same code, so it continues the `for` loop that the parent started.

Comment: Don't use `printf` to print error messages.  Either use `perror` or `fprintf` and explicitly write to stderr.

Comment: See also [Synchronizing N sibling processes after `fork()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53734028/synchronising-n-sibling-processes-after-fork)  In this context, you'd have the children all wait for the parent to let them run, and the parent would write all the child PIDs out before letting them run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really want to complete your assignment for you, but I would suggest starting with something similar to this:

```
void child_func(int readfd) {
    // read from readfd and do whatever
}

void do_fork(pid_t *childpid, int *pipefd) {
    int pipefds[2];
    pid_t pid;
    pipe(pipefds, 0);
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
        child_func(pipefds[0]);
        exit(0);
    } else {
        *childpid = pid;
        *pipefd = pipefds[1];
    }
}

int main() {
    int i;
    pid_t children[5];
    int pipes[5];
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        do_fork(&children[i], &pipes[i]);
    }
    // whatever
    return 0;
}
```

If your child_func reads from the file descriptor at the beginning, it will block until the parent writes to the other 5 descriptors.  That would give you a chance to print out the pids or whatever and then tell them what to do.  Look at the man pages for "pipe" and "fork" if you don't understand this completely.  I hope that is enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to use that!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to completely miss the point of `fork`. It is a very special function - it returns either `0` or non-negative integer, or -1. The first thing you need to do after the fork is to check the return value.

If it is non-negative, that means, you are executing in a parent and you can continue your parental thing. The return value is a PID of a child process just spawn.

If it is `-1`, there was an error (very weird case), and if it is 0, it means you are now executing in a child process, and you should do something else - something which child is expected to do.

Any code where result of `fork` is not checked immediately with branch for parent a child process is always a buggy code.